# problem with System.in for logical testing java code in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, inputstream, bytearrayoutputstream, system.in

i change standard `System.in` to pass my test cases cause the code reads input from System.in. In multi-thread environment like servlet changing the standard System.in will give problems. Is there any other way to pass test cases to System.in without using `System.setIn()`?

My servlet get's a Java code as string and i compile and load class in-memory for logical testing that java code. so i will pass my test cases to check the output.

That test code read inputs from System.in so i change the System.in into custom `ByteArrayInputStream` with my custom input and process the java code.

while processing, if servlet get a concurrent another request (request B) that will use `System.in` set by request A so it conflicts with test cases. if any another way to pass my test cases into `System.in` ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *"As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking"* Nope :) The question is perfectly clear. Just stop downvoting/closevoting questions beyond your expertiste/understanding :z